# LibGdx: Table not displayed correctly

Tags: java, android, layout, libgdx

I have a table in libgdx which is supposed to have 6 buttons, organised into 2 rows. Here's my code:

```
        elementsTable.clear();
        String[] colors = new String [6];
        colors[0] = "red";
        colors[1] = "orange";
        colors[2] = "yellow";
        colors[3] = "purple";
        colors[4] = "blue";
        colors[5] = "green";

        String category = currentCategory.name();
        category = category.substring(0, category.length()-1).toLowerCase(); //removes the last character because otherwise there would be an extra 's'

        int count = 0;
        for(String color : colors) {
            ButtonStyle buttonStyle = new ButtonStyle();
            buttonStyle.up = cellsSkin.getDrawable(category + "_" + color);
            Button button = new Button(buttonStyle);
            button.addListener(toolBoxListener);
            button.setName(category + "_" + color);
            button.setSize(toolBoxButtonSize, toolBoxButtonSize);
            elementsTable.add(button).pad(toolBoxButtonPadding);

            count ++;
            if (count == Math.ceil((colors.length/2d))) elementsTable.row();
        }
```

That's the filling. My buttons are of 6 different colors so I loop over the array with the color names to access the skin to get the drawable for the buttons. This part seems to work because when I debug and look at the table, it has the 6 buttons in there with the right size.

Then I set the position and size of my table and add it to the stage.:

```
    elementsTable.setSize(toolBoxWidth, 500/(float)(3*toolBoxButtonSize+6*toolBoxButtonPadding)*elementsTable.getHeight());
    elementsTable.setPosition(195, 30);
    stage.addActor(elementsTable);
```

The stage has an orthographic camera set that should scale things down just fine.

However, what I get is this:
[image: The layout is screwed up.]

Another strange thin is that when I look at the table's height and width in debug mode, it says 0 even thoug there are elements in it that all have the corrct size.

Can anyone help me?

If you have any further questions on the problem, please ask! I tried to give a detailed description, but I am happy to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

It seemsits just the position. 30 is too low for the Y:

```
elementsTable.setPosition(195, 30);
```

Try 150 for example:

```
elementsTable.setPosition(195, 150);
```

Remember the coordinate system that Libgdx (and OpenGL) use is with Y going up.

Comment: dont forget that the `setPosition(float x, float y)` does set the center of the table to the given position. So 30 would mean, that the center of the table is 30px above the bottom of the screen. I recommend to simply center it by `table.setPosition(cam.viewportWidth / 2,cam.viewportHeight / 2);` to test if its the table